# RxJava - How to avoid this race condition?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to insert some data into the local database on a background thread with a `Completeable` inside the constructor of my `ViewModel`

```
public MainViewModel() extends ViewModel {

    public MainViewModel(){
        localRepository.insertValueIntoDatabase().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(() -> {
                        sharedPrefManager.setAnotherValue(true);
                    }, throwable -> {
                        Timber.e(throwable, "Failed to insert into DB");
                    });
    }
}
```

In my `MainActivity` I am also calling a method after the construction of the `MainViewModel` that will perform a query based on the inserted value in the constructor.

```
viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
viewModel.performQueryWithValue();
```

```
public MainViewModel() extends ViewModel {

    public MainViewModel(){
        localRepository.insertValueIntoDatabase().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .subscribe(() -> {
                        sharedPrefManager.setAnotherValue(true);
                    }, throwable -> {
                        Timber.e(throwable, "Failed to insert into DB");
                    });
    }

    public void performQueryWithValue(){
        localRepository.getValueFromDatabase().flatMapSingle(value -> {
             if(value == 0){
                return remoteRepository.performQueryOne();
             }else{
                return remoteRepositoru.performQueryTwo();
             }

        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(result-> {
                   
                    
        }, err -> {
            
        });
    }
}
```

If the  `localRepository.insertValueIntoDatabase()` takes 10 seconds to insert,

How do I make the `performQueryWithValue()` method wait for the completion of the insert before performing the query?

Comment: Can you not listen for it? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is not the calls themselves, but the nature of attempting 2 different, ***independent asynchronies*** calls against a local DB.

Let's assume that the local DB is **Room**.
Room allows READ access from *multiple threads* and has some internal rules for WRITE access.

Your use of `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` itself will not mean that the access calls will happen sequentially, with the second call waiting for the first to finish. That's is not how the `Schedulers` works.
All the `Schedulers` do in essence is to have actions happen *on a specific thread* with no guarantee of any kind of sequence.

To be able to guarantee that the WRITE happens before the READ, you have 2 options.

Options 1:
You force the sequences to happen one after another by only calling the READ ***after*** you are certain that the WRITE has completed. This can be achieved by using the Rx chain like below:

```
localRepository.insertValueIntoDatabase() // <- WRITE
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .flatMap { performQueryWithValue() } // <- READ
        .subscribe(result -> {
            sharedPrefManager.setAnotherValue(true);
            // DO something with the data pulled from the local DB
        }, throwable -> {
            Timber.e(throwable, "Failed to insert into DB");
        });
```

Option 2:
You perform the WRITE, but setup the READ as an **Observation** instead of the *pull* you are doing now. An Observation will only be triggered ***after*** new data exists, so you are guaranteed to only get new data ***when*** new data becomes available. Room, for example allows for this by defining the return from a Room query to be an **Observable**.

```
localRepository.insertValueIntoDatabase() // <- WRITE
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(() -> {
            sharedPrefManager.setAnotherValue(true);
        }, throwable -> {
            Timber.e(throwable, "Failed to insert into DB");
        });


public void performQueryWithValue(){
    localRepository.observeValueFromDatabase() // <- OBSERVATION
        .flatMapSingle(value -> {
             if(value == 0){
                return remoteRepository.performQueryOne();
             }else{
                return remoteRepositoru.performQueryTwo();
             }

        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(result-> {
             // DO something with the data observed from the local DB   
        }, err -> {
            
        });
    }
```

Great guide to Option 2 [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) by Florina Muntenescu.

Answer (score 0):

You can call `performQueryWithValue()` method after successful `insertValueIntoDatabase` execution like this:

```
localRepository.insertValueIntoDatabase()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(() -> {
            sharedPrefManager.setAnotherValue(true);
            performQueryWithValue();
        }, throwable -> {
            Timber.e(throwable, "Failed to insert into DB");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you chain these calls together? Something like this (This code might have compile errors)

```java
localRepository
    .insertValueIntoDatabase()
    .flatMap {
        sharedPrefManager.setAnotherValue(true);
        return localRepository.getValueFromDatabase();
    }
    .flatMapSingle(value -> {
        if (value == 0) {
            return remoteRepository.performQueryOne();
        } else {
            return remoteRepositoru.performQueryTwo();
        }
    })
    .subscribe(() -> {
         
    }, throwable -> {
        Timber.e(throwable, "Failed to insert into DB");
    });
```

This way, these methods will get called sequentially.